# iOS animate UIPickerView inside static UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-graphics

I have a static `UITableViewCell` with `UIPickerViews` inside the cells. I am trying to animate the cell to be shown when the cell above it is clicked. I used `[self.tableview beginUpdates]` and `[self.tableView endUpdates]` to animate the cell itself which slides down nicely into place. The `UIPickerView` however, appears on the screen before the animation for the cell finishes loading and looks very ugly. How can I animate it so that it slides along with the `UITableViewCell`?

I also don't understand why it is not cut off by the expanding cell, since it is inside the cell shouldn't it grow along with the cell and not just appear at once?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Show your code between the table update would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I figured it out. Had to have cell.autoresizingMask= UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight; and cell.clipsToBounds = YES; enabled for the cell. Can't believe it took three hours to solve this.